# SQL Server not using index for top + order by

Tags: sql-server

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    [Trade_US_PC].[ID] 
FROM 
    [Trade_US_PC] 
INNER JOIN 
    [Item] ON ([Trade_US_PC].[ItemID] = [Item].[ID]) 
WHERE 
    ([Trade_US_PC].[ItemTraitsID] = 14) 
ORDER BY 
    [Item].Name_EN
```

- `Trade_US_PC.ID` and `Item.ID` are primary keys
- `[Trade_US_PC].[ItemID]` is a foreign key on `Item.ID` and is indexed `CREATE INDEX IX_Trade_US_PC_ItemID ON Trade_US_PC(ItemID);`
- `[Trade_US_PC].[ItemTraitsID]` is a Nullable column foreign key on another table, and is Spatial Indexed `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FTIX_Trade_US_PC_ItemTraitID ON Trade_US_PC(ItemTraitsID) WHERE ItemTraitsID IS NOT NULL;`
- `Item.Name_EN` is indexed `CREATE INDEX IX_Item_Name_EN ON Item(Name_EN)`

Problem is that the query is not using the `Name_EN` index when performing `Top 10` and `order by`.

[image]

What can I do to get rid of the costly Top N Sort?

Comment: Why do you think its slow? What are the number of reads (`SET STATISTICS IO ON`)? A query plan time always has to have all its operations add up to 100% of the total execution time so something will always have a high percentage somewhere but that does not mean that this part is not efficient or slow.

Comment: @Igor my table got over 400k rows and the query couldn't even finish in 5 min.

Comment: If you remove the ORDER BY then what is the duration? Also what is the results read from SET STATISTICS IO ON (interested in reads and scans). Also can you provide the DDL?

Comment: Another thought, did you check for index fragementation on index `IX_Item_Name_EN`?

Comment: @Igor fragmentation 98.08% and 67.37 page fullness. Query is still running IDK if I can get the statistics in the next hour

Comment: Which table has 400K rows? Or is that the total number of records in the resultset? Is it possible that you're doing an incomplete `JOIN` causing  duplicates records (like a `CROSS JOIN`) and getting millions of records that you're trying to sort?

Comment: @alroc Trade_PC_US has 400k rows, item has around 8k

Comment: Fragmentation 98.08% might be the problem :). I would rebuild that index and see what the results are once that completes. Query still running across 400k does not sound right. Maybe a possible cartesian product in the join like @alroc suggested. You can test this by removing the WHERE and ORDER clauses and setting a COUNT as the result in the select.

Comment: One more question. Can I assume that the primary keys on both tables are clustered primary keys? If not then you might have to tune that index on `IX_Item_Name_EN` to [include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) the `ID` column.

Comment: @Igor yea they are both Clustered primary keys. I have noticed something fishy...even if the query plan shows 99% Index Seek/Key lookup the query wont finish even after 30min

Comment: @Igor After rebuilding the Index and adding an index to include Trade_US_PC.ID I was able to get this query to run in 2s. But something else fishy happened. Going to open up another question for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for index fragmentation on the index `IX_Item_Name_EN`. If this is heavily fragmented it could explain the execution plan results and also the long time it takes to execute. If it is heavily fragmented you can rebuild it which should speed up the query significantly (if it is fragmented).

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that Sort Operator is a blocking operator and this explain the highly cost that it consume in your statement, the other thing that you need to know is the fact that <>Operator NOT use any index, because it's a operation which does not filter (is not a predicate) for this never can take advantages of indexes (clustered or nonclustered).

You can use for analyzing your Query the next statements to evaluate the different metrics:

```
SET STATISTICS IO
SET STATISTICS TIME
```